# Convert Sumologic Queries to Kibana

Tags: kibana, sumologic

I am in the early stages of migrating my observability solution from Sumo Logic to Kibana.  Assuming the data (logs) in to each system is the same: is it possible to convert Sumo Logic queries to their Kibana equivalent?  I would like to avoid doing each of these manually and do it in a programmatic way since there are hundreds of these queries.